# Primavera P6 Integration API : System property 'primavera.bootstrap.home' not found

Tags: weblogic, primavera

We are trying to deploy primavera integration API in weblogic. While deploying "PrimaveraAPI.war" getting below error.

We are using Primavera P6 Enterprise Project Portfolio Management 17.12.

Refreshing com.primavera.bre.SystemApplicationContext@2bbbd70c: startup date [Thu Jan 23 21:03:32 IST 2020]; root of context hierarchy

Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/primavera/bre/integration/intgconf.xml]
System property 'primavera.bootstrap.home' not found

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try setting the property in question in your JAVA_OPTIONS? Ideally that can be set in setDomainEnv.sh or startWeblogic.sh

Comment: Thanks Naveen.

I have added -Dprimavera.bootstrap.home path at condition added bottom of startWebLogic.cmd file. 

if "%WLS_REDIRECT_LOG%"=="" (
 echo Starting WLS with line: 
 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java %JAVA_VM% -Dprimavera.bootstrap.home=D:/Test/P6IntegrationAPI_11 %MEM_ARGS% ....

) else ( 
 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -Dprimavera.bootstrap.home=D:/Test/P6IntegrationAPI_11 %JAVA_VM% %MEM_ARGS% .... 
)

Above changes works for me and application start without any error.